# Error using pymssql when creating database users in SQL Server

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pymssql

I am getting the below error whenever I am trying to create a new user on a database.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src\pymssql\_pymssql.pyx", line 460, in pymssql._pymssql.Cursor.execute
  File "src\pymssql\_mssql.pyx", line 1104, in pymssql._mssql.MSSQLConnection.execute_query
  File "src\pymssql\_mssql.pyx", line 1135, in pymssql._mssql.MSSQLConnection.execute_query
  File "src\pymssql\_mssql.pyx", line 1268, in pymssql._mssql.MSSQLConnection.format_and_run_query
  File "src\pymssql\_mssql.pyx", line 1806, in pymssql._mssql.check_cancel_and_raise
  File "src\pymssql\_mssql.pyx", line 1852, in pymssql._mssql.raise_MSSQLDatabaseException
pymssql._mssql.MSSQLDatabaseException: (102, b"Incorrect syntax near 'CREATE USER [test_login] FOR LOGIN [test_login] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]'.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 15:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n")

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_sqlserver.py", line 60, in <module>
    createUsers(row[0][:-1], target_server, target_database)
  File "test_sqlserver.py", line 44, in createUsers
    cursor.execute('%s', sqlStatement)
  File "src\pymssql\_pymssql.pyx", line 475, in pymssql._pymssql.Cursor.execute
pymssql._pymssql.ProgrammingError: (102, b"Incorrect syntax near 'CREATE USER [test_login] FOR LOGIN [test_login] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]'.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 15:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n")
```

Below is my code currently.

```
def createUsers(sqlStatement, server, database):
    conn = pymssql.connect(server=server, database=database)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('%s', sqlStatement)


target_server = 'MYServer'
target_database = 'MYDatabase'
sqlStatement = 'CREATE USER [test_login] FOR LOGIN [test_login] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]'

createUsers(sqlStatement, target_server, target_database)
```

I am not sure why I am getting this error as I can execute the SQL statement directly on the database without any issues. And I can also use pymssql to query information from the database. But whenever I try to create a new user on the database, I keep getting this error. Is anyone familiar with this?

Answer (score 0):

Issue was resolved after changing cursor.execute statement to below

```
cursor.execute(sqlStatement)
```

I also had to add the below commit, otherwise the changes were not being seen on the database side.

```
conn.commit()
```